# What kind of relations between `tabs` and `workers` entities in FF addons?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm newby to FF Add-Ons and its SDK, so I'm trying to figure out some basic concepts. 
The first thing I wish to clarify - relations between `tabs-sdk` and `workers`. As I got from documentation - every time I attach content-scripts to tab via

```
this.activeWorker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScript: script
});
```

I'm getting a `worker`. But my question is: "Is it a totally new `worker`, related to the same `activeTab`?" If so, does it mean, that the next statement is correct?

```
var firstWorker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScript: someScript
});

var secondWorker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScript: someOtherScript
});

var isEqual = (firstWorker === secondWorker); //false
```

And if it's correct, the next question is: "Is there a way, to listen for messages on tab and not on worker?"

Comment: why do you need to listen on the tab and not on workers?

Comment: And why not? My only need is to listen for messages sent from `background`-script to the `active tab` and send something back if needed. So in case all tab-attached scripts work in same scope, I don't even need to know anything about workers. I just think in a way it's done in Chrome, where it is possible to listen for broadcasted messages in `background`-scripts where you can get `tab.id` and compare it to `activeTab.id`. And if you send message from `background` to `content` script you can specify `tab.id` of recipient.

Comment: I asked why you *need* to do that, not why you *want* to do it. Since there doesn't seem to be any, I suggest simply looking at the [attach options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach%28options%29)

Comment: Yes, I agree, there is no such necessity, it's more for a personal convenience. But what about my main question? Could you please give me some advices or clarify this thing with relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each invocation of attach gives you a new, independent worker.

And to listen for messages from each worker you simply pass your callback function every time you create one.